# Deny DynamoDB Access if IP address not on allow list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, whitelist

I'm trying to restrict access to the state lock management DynamoDB table. (Terraform)
I understand that DynamoDB does not support resource based policies and you have to set it in a role, however I'm not actually 100% sure of that either.

The thing is that, although the policy applies greatly, it is not working. Variable details are perfekt. Important is to say I authenticate to Terraform with Short Term credentials by setting the AWs environments variables you get in the Portal and I have Administrator Access. However, I understand that an explicit deny always overwrites any allows.

I know that it is not working because I change the value of IP variable to something different and I am still able to obtain statelock info when terraform apply.

json (I have tried allow also)

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": <myip>
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource":<myarn>
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how it looks using data iam policy document

```hcl
resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
    name                = "${var.dynamodb_name}-ip-restrict-role"
    assume_role_policy  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
}


data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role" {
    statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["dynamodb.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    }
}




resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "dynamodb_policy" {
    name   = "${var.dynamodb_name}-ip-restrict-policy"
    policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.dynamodb_policy_document.json
    role   = aws_iam_role.role.id
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "dynamodb_policy_document" {
     statement {
     resources = [aws_dynamodb_table.dynamodb.arn]
     effect    = "Deny"

     actions   = [
      "dynamodb:*"
     ]

     condition {
      test     = "NotIpAddress"
      variable = "aws:SourceIp"
      values   = var.whitelisted_ips_dynamo
       }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update: 21.03.2024

Two days after you asked the question, [AWS released resource based policies for DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simplify-cross-account-access-control-with-amazon-dynamodb-using-resource-based-policies/), you're in luck!
It may take a few more days until terraform supports them, but now you're able to create a policy like this and attach it to your table:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*Item*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "1.1.1.1"
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:123123123123:table/demotable"
        }
    ]
}
```

Be careful though, you may lock yourself out from managing that table if you use `dynamodb:*` in the action, I suggest you use `dynamodb:*Item*`, which would still allow you to update the table properties if you're not from a whitelisted IP.

---

### Outdated answer

You're correct, that DynamoDB supports no resource-based permissions that would allow you to limit access to certain IP addresses.

I tried your setup with this policy on my IAM User:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "1.1.1.1"
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:123123123:table/demotable"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any I was successfully locked out:

```bash
$ aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name demotable

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeTable operation:
User: arn:aws:iam::123123123123:user/myuser is not authorized to perform: 
dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:123123123123:table/demotable
with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy
```

Changing the `SourceIp` to my actual IP allowed me to describe the table (the user has an admin policy).

```bash
$ aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name demotable --output yaml --no-cli-pager
Table:
  AttributeDefinitions:
  - AttributeName: GSI1PK
    AttributeType: S
  - AttributeName: GSI1SK
    AttributeType: S
  - AttributeName: PK
    AttributeType: S
  - AttributeName: SK
# ...
```

I suggest you check you double check your IPs and resource ARN, the policy itself looks fine aside from that.

Comment: Thank you. All values are correct. However, I think in my policy the role gets used by dynamo service itself and not by any user, correct me if I am wrong please. Attaching this policy-role to an user would only be valid for the user specifically. Is there a way to block access to the table for anyone who does not have that IP, period.

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding, you can't "make" a service use a role by putting the service as the principal in a role. If you need to enforce this IP-restriction, the only way to do it besides attaching this policy to all relevant roles is adding a Service Control Policy to the whole account, which only works if you're using AWS Organizations - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_syntax.html

Comment: You're in luck @JorgeMartínez, AWS listened to your wishes and released resource based policies for DynamoDB, I updated the answer ;)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much. Is there a way to know exactly when terraform is gonna update on this regard?

Comment: Hard to say, but usually they're fast ;-) I suggest you pay attention to the release notes of the terraform aws provider: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/releases

Answer (score 0):

I would use a VPCe policy for this, if the requests are coming from within AWS (EC2, Lambda, etc...).

Adding a VPCe for DynamoDB adds no additional cost, but forces all of your traffic to go via the endpoint, which allows you to specify its own IAM policy, which treats it almost like a resource based policy, that you don't have to define on each role/user.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints-dynamodb.html